# Run one solution(.sln file) from another solution

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have 2 solution files S1 and S2.

S2 has to run first and then S1 should run, because S1 has files that are dependent on the output of S2.

Is it possible to include solution S2 within S1, so that when I run S1, the execution starts with S2, and once S2 is completed then S1 is executed ? If possible, could you please tell me how to do so.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't *run* solutions. Visual Studio ***compiles*** solutions (and only one per instance of VS running). The resulting executables are run by the operating system (unless you are debugging them). So the answer is: no, you can't. You could make the executable S2 run the process of the executable S1 if that's what you want, but that has nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: I assume you are talking in a debugging scenario like previous comment said.
As solutions are just collections of projects, and what VS run is a project, why don't add the projects from S1 than you need into S2. In this case all projects will be loaded by VS and you'll be able to start all the projects needed.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Pre-Build-Action and call MSBuild on your own. Syntax is like:

```
MSBuild MyApp.sln /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
```

Comment: That won't `execute` a solution. That'd `build` a solution. It *might* happen to be what the OP wanted to express, but taken how the question is redacted, this is not really answering the question.

Comment: @Jcl Agreed, but I assume OP is non-native and this is a language issue (and maybe also an F5-issue). So if you think over the edge, that seems exactly what he was asking for (binary output of another solution).

Comment: When I read it, I actually thought that there should be a executable ran after another since the input of one executable depended on the first (and it made no sense if talking about Visual Studio). You may be right though.